# AsyncDisplayKey - stacklayout doesnt shows on screen

Tags: asyncdisplaykit

I try to create stacklayout inside cellnode, but nothing shows on screen

```
class Node: ASCellNode {

    let blackNode = ASDisplayNode()
    let blueNode = ASDisplayNode()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addSubnode(blueNode)
        self.addSubnode(blackNode)
    }

    override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        blackNode.backgroundColor = .black
        blueNode.backgroundColor = .blue


        let contentStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .horizontal,
                                                spacing: 40,
                                                justifyContent: .start,
                                                alignItems: .center,
                                                children: [blackNode, blueNode])

        contentStackSpec.style.minWidth = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(60.0);
        contentStackSpec.style.maxHeight = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(40.0);

        return ASRelativeLayoutSpec(horizontalPosition: .center, verticalPosition: .center, sizingOption: .init(rawValue: 0), child: contentStackSpec)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe something wrong in ASRelativeLayoutSpec, try to return `contentStackSpec` for test.

Comment: And i didn't see anyRule for sizing blueNode and blackNode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ASInsetLayoutSpec` for displaying `ASStackLayoutSpec` instead of `ASRelativeLayoutSpec`.

Below is the implementation of your given code using `ASInsetLayoutSpec` for displaying `ASStackLayoutSpec`:

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        blackNode.backgroundColor = .black
        blueNode.backgroundColor = .blue


        let contentStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec(direction: .horizontal,
                                                spacing: 40,
                                                justifyContent: .start,
                                                alignItems: .center,
                                                children: [blackNode, blueNode])

        contentStackSpec.style.minWidth = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(60.0);
        contentStackSpec.style.maxHeight = ASDimensionMakeWithPoints(40.0);

        let cardInsetSpec : ASInsetLayoutSpec = ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5), child: contentStackSpec)  

        return cardInsetSpec

    }
```